# Gstreamer total latancy

Tags: gstreamer

Goal:

Measure the whole Pipeline time thats​ need a frame from the Stream src to the sink. The src is a IP camera and we should detect how long take a frame from the camera to the sink, If the time to high we should Show something in the Display.

Can you guys explain me how is this measurment possible in gstreamer ?
Our gstreamer Applikation is written in c++ some hints or code examples are welcome

Thank you du mucj guys

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275647/measuring-latency-in-a-gstreamer-pipeline/728408#728408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pad probes perhaps:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html#using-probes

Depending on your pipeline behavior - you would choose the earliest element that can access reasonable data (not sure what the camera delivers as samples in your case) record the current system's time to the sample's DTS/PTS (frame reordering may be a pitfall here) and do the same thing at the last pad you have access to.

Compare the system's times of a sample with the same PTS/DTS and you should have the time delta the sample spend in the pipeline. Depending on your required accuracy this may be a good enough estimate.